# how to find the _id value from subdocuments at mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection like the one below, I want to get the `_id` value from the `offerObject` subdocument, I am using `mongoTemplate` in the Spring framework.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("543be5f3cbdf2e1eb442cb81"),`

  "_class" : "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject",

  "offerObject" : {

    "_id" : ObjectId("543bbb7ecbdf85c6ceb44f33"),

    "type" : "offer"
   }
}
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used MongoTemplate, but based off previous experience doing java programming with Mongo, it would look something like this:

```
// Pull a document from the Collection
MongoDummyObject mdo = yourTemplate.findOne(query, MongDummyObject.class);

// Get the offer Object from the MongoDummyObject
OfferObject offerObject = mdo.getOfferObject();

// Pull the id from the offer object
String id = offerObject.getId();
```